# App crashes after implementing splashscreen

Tags: android, xml

After implementing an splash screen following an answer here on Stack I get crashes upon opening the app. The errors show up in my logcat as the app is opening.
    
Here's my code:
Android Manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="se.welovecode.tismatapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="se.welovecode.tismatapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="se.welovecode.tismatapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".ParsePushApplication">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- PARSE PUSH NOTIFICATION -->
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="se.welovecode.tismatapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="se.welovecode.tismatapp.MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<activity
    android:name="MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="splashScreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

Logcat: [Drive document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-rByjddQwuICclF_s58Y_pkIP99oczVIzOpRW9CqA7k/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please do not create splash screens.  There is nothing good about them and users hate them.  They are anti-Android.   http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an activity tag in your layout XML. That's not how it works. Activity tags are only intended for your manifest. The layout XML files should only have views and maybe fragments. Activities are usually full screens.

You can read more about what goes in your manifest here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

And you can read about what goes in layout XML here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: Fixed it but got some error, nothing that crashed the app! Thank you so much!

Comment: No, the activity tag is only used to tell Android that you have an activity in your code. Layout XML is used to define what the screen will look like, and you define that in terms of views. Adding links to my answer...

Comment: So this shouldn't have fixed it? Cause it did?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was mainly that the attributes in a manifest are different than the ones in a layout. You do want name, label, and theme in the manifest. You don't want layout_width or layout_height. Those are only meaningful in a layout.